# Trainable sklearn StandardScaler for R

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

Is there something similar in `R` that allows to fit a [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) (resulting into mean=0 and standard deviation=1 features) to the training data and use that scaler model to transform the test data? [`scale`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scale.html) does not offer a way to transform test-data based on the mean and standard deviation from the training data.

Snippet for `Python`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Since I'm pretty sure that this is the right way to do so ([avoiding the leak of information from the test to the training set](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i)) I guess there is a simple solution I'm just unable to find.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that the [`scale`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scale.html) function in `R` does what you are looking for. For your example, that would just be

```
X_train_scaled = scale(X_train)
```

Then, you can apply the mean and sd from the scaled training set to your test set using the `attr` (attributes) from your scaled X_train:

```
X_test_scaled = scale(X_test, center=attr(X_train_scaled, "scaled:center"), 
                              scale=attr(X_train_scaled, "scaled:scale"))
```

This obtains the exact results as the transformations from the [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i) that you posted

Comment: I'm familiar with that one. But how do you use the information of mean and sd from the training set to transform the test set ?

Comment: See my edit, I'm pretty sure `scale` with the correct arguments will do